# BLAS Replacement causes failure of matrix multiplication in Linux but not in windows

Tags: c++, linux, linker, blas, armadillo

I have downloaded and installed package [qpOASES](https://projects.coin-or.org/qpOASES).

Considering the following code:

```
#define ARMA_DONT_USE_CXX11 /* In Cygwin */
#include <armadillo>

int main()
{

    arma::mat A;
    A
        <<0.0119<<0<<arma::endr
        <<0.0237<<0.0119<<arma::endr
        <<0.0354<<0.0437<<arma::endr
        <<0.0469<<0.0354;

    arma::mat B;
    B
    <<1.0<<0<<0<<0<<arma::endr
    <<0<<1.0<<0<<0<<arma::endr
    <<0<<0<<1.0<<0<<arma::endr
    <<0<<0<<0<<1.0;

    std::cout<<"A^T*B:"<<std::endl<<A.t()*B<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I multiply two matrices it runs ok in windows:

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o bin/example1 -I/cygdrive/d/tmp/qpoases/qpOASES/include -I'C:\cygwin\usr\local\include\' -I'C:\cygwin\usr\include' -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -lqpOASES -larmadillo -L'C:\cygwin\usr\local\lib\' /cygdrive/d/tmp/qpoases/qpOASES/src/BLASReplacement.o -L/cygdrive/d/tmp/qpoases/qpOASES/bin /cygdrive/d/tmp/qpoases/qpOASES/src/LAPACKReplacement.o -Wfatal-errors -Wconversion

./bin/example1
A^T*B:
   0.0119   0.0237   0.0354   0.0469
        0   0.0119   0.0437   0.0354
```

But it fails under Linux (Ubuntu):

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -g -o bin/example1  -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -lqpOASES -larmadillo  -L'qpoases' qpOASES/LAPACKReplacement.o qpOASES/BLASReplacement.o -Wfatal-errors -Wconversion

./bin/example1
A^T*B:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have realized that what causes error is the `BLASReplacement`. So removing `BLASReplacement` the program works fine:

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -g -o bin/example1  -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -lqpOASES -larmadillo  -L'qpoases' qpOASES/LAPACKReplacement.o -Wfatal-errors -Wconversion

./bin/example1
A^T*B:
   0.0119   0.0237   0.0354   0.0469
        0   0.0119   0.0437   0.0354
```

Here is a quick access to [BLASReplacement.cpp](https://github.com/asherikov/qpOASES/blob/master/src/BLASReplacement.cpp).

It seems using `qpOASES` and `armadillo` together makes problem for me using Linux. What causes this problem and why this problem does not exist in my Windows?

---

**UPDATE**

I used code-block as a debugger and found the last line causing error:

```
typedef double T;
arma_fortran(arma_dgemm)(transA, transB, m, n, k, (const T*)alpha, (const T*)A, ldA, (const T*)B, ldB, (const T*)beta, (T*)C, ldC);
```

And the definition of this wrapper is in `def_blas.hpp`

```
extern "C"
  {
     ...
     void arma_fortran(arma_dgemm)(const char* transA, const char* transB, const blas_int* m, const blas_int* n, const blas_int* k, const double* alpha, const double* A, const blas_int* ldA, const double* B, const blas_int* ldB, const double* beta, double* C, const blas_int* ldC);
     ...
  }
```

A github fork to `Armadillo` library is [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/).

It is in `blas_wrapper.hpp` inside `armadillo` seems `dgemm` of `armadillo` and `BLASReplacement.o` of `qpOASES` are clashing. What is the best way to get around it?

Comment: You might consider running it in a debugger to see where the crash is.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks. I  have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this old, but qpOASES fix this issue in 2021: https://github.com/coin-or/qpOASES/pull/108

Back at the time the question is first posted, the best option might be prefix all exported functions in BLASReplacement.hpp/cpp to make it not compatible with BLAS apis.